# How to combine multer uploads?

Tags: javascript, mern, multer

I need to be able to upload a single image AND an array of images (both are optional fields on the frontend so I want to keep them separate). My code works if I use one upload or the other. How do I properly combine `upload.single('frontImage')` and `upload.array('files[]')`?

```
router.post(
  '/create',
  upload.single('frontImage').array('files[]'), /// <-- HOW DO I WRITE THIS LINE?
  [check('title').not().isEmpty()],
  flashCardsControllers.createFlashCard
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *[`.fields()`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#fieldsfields)* method which handles multiple file fields with different field names. A sample would look something like:

```js
router.post(
  '/create',
  upload.fields([{ name: 'frontImage', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'files[]' }]),
  [check('title').not().isEmpty()],
  flashCardsControllers.createFlashCard
);
```

This will allow you to handle both `frontImage` and `files[]` fields when uploading files. The `maxCount` property is used to limit the number of files for a specific field, in this case, we set it to `1` for the `frontImage` field.